# [C]Erdos-Renyi graph: "Loop will run at most once" error

Tags: c, graph

I am writing the C code for an Erdos-Renyi graph. I hope that the 'if condition' for creating edges could be correct (I need to consider a uniform distribution, in order to satisfy the connectivity of the graph). However I have received this message "Loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed" (please have a look at (*) in my code):

Comment: Well, you have a return statement in your `for`-loop, so obviously there can only be a single iteration. Probably you want to have that return statement at the very end of your function.

Comment: Thank you, Ben Steffan. I have just done what you said. However there is no output in this way now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben Steffan said, the `return` statement should be outside of the for loop. The reason why there is not output is because you are not printing anything. I'm not sure how you want to display the data, but the two most common ways would be to print to console (`stdin`) or to a file.